# Limiting CiviVolunteer to certain group

Tags: civivolunteer

I am uncertain if there is a way to accomplish this but am hoping so. When our organization has an event, we utilize volunteers to work various aspects of the event. Obviously, this is what CiviVolunteer is designed to do. Where I am running into an issue is to have CiviVolunteer limited to a particular group.

So, currently when you go to an event page, a visitor has a means to register for the event. Additionally, using CiviVolunteer module, someone can register as a volunteer. How can I limit the volunteers to our group of volunteers that have been trained, passed background checks, etc.  I want to avoid confusion on the registration page when someone visits the page. Is there a way to set up a private link to our volunteer staff where they can sign up for their desired roles?